# How to improve the efficiency of my python script that imports data?

Tags: python, sql, database, import, migration

Here is my code. It connects to SQL Server and queries data from it, then it connects to MariaDB and writes the dataframe to a MariaDB empty table in the database. Basically, I am importing data from SQL->MariaDB using this script.

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

#connect to MariaDB via mysql

username='user'
password='pass'
host='host'
port=port
database='database'
mdb_cnxn = f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}"
engine = create_engine(mdb_cnxn)

#connect to SQL Server via pyodbc

server = 'server'
database = 'database'
sql_cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';Trusted_connection=yes')

#sql query to query SQL database

query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME"
df = pd.read_sql(query, sql_cnxn)
sql_cnxn.close()

#Write the DataFrame to a MariaDB table

df.to_sql('TABLE_NAME', engine, if_exists='append', index=False, method='multi', chunksize=10000)
engine.dispose()
```

It works for some tables, and for others it errors out due to memory issues. There is no specific python error, my server just crashes and my VSCode says it needs to restart. I don't know if there is a better way to write the code to import the data, or maybe the code isn't the issue? I am not sure.

I guess I can create an ODS layer then merge to a final table once I load the data?

Comment: I don't know what the issue is for sure, but your question strongly suggests that your SELECT just blows the RAM. What do you get from `query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME"` (assuming that `TABLE_NAME` is a deliberate placeholder)?

Comment: The tables that are erroring out have between 3mil-6mil records. It's weird because I imported some tables that have 5mil records perfectly fine.

Comment: It doesn't just matter about the row count (that was just for me to take a ballpark). It also matters what number of columns there are and their datatypes. Have you monitored memory during the process with `htop` to see whether you explode the resources?